# Integrate Huawei Mobile Services in React Native app based on Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed an app with `React Native` based on `Expo SDK`, how can I integrate `HMS` in my project to make it work for `Huawei` devices?
Shall I introduce conditional branches to either use `expo-location` instead of `hms location` or viceversa or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> Shall I introduce conditional branches to either use expo-location instead of hms location or viceversa or is there a better way?

Condition judgment needs to be used to distinguish different mobile phone environments. You could use other methods or use the [HMS Availability plug-in](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/client-dev-0000001138591439).

The React Native Plugin provides adaption code used for the HUAWEI Location Kit to be used in the React Native platform. For details about HUAWEI Location Kit, please
kindly refer to [This Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050142177).